# Undefined index error while submitting form

Tags: php

I have used a script to hide an input when an option value is selected. The form gets submitted but gives me an undefined index error for the variable which i have hidden. My script is as follows:

```
function Sbox()
{
  if(document.getElementById("selectdrop").value=='2')
  {
  document.getElementById("text2").disabled=true;
  }
}
```

and my form is a s follows:

```
<form action="" method="POST>
<select name="text1" id="selectdrop" onchange="return Sbox();">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="text2" name="text2"/>
</form>
```

when I select option 2, textbox2 is disabled. But when I submit the form , my data is being inserted but is showing an error of undefined index for text2.

My PHP code for submit is as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$text1=$_POST['text1'];
$text2=$_POST['text2'];
$sql="INSERT INTO letters (text1 , text2) VALUES ('$text1' , '$text2')";
  if(mysqli_query($connect , $sql)==true){

    echo "data has been successfully entered";

  }
  else{
    echo "data not entered";
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's the php code that the question tag promised?

Comment: Sorry, added the PHP code

Comment: As @smitraval said, disabled elements don't get sent in POST requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are disabling text2. Try using following code and it should work fine.

```
function Sbox()
{
  if(document.getElementById("selectdrop").value=='2')
  {
  var s = document.getElementById("text2");
  s.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
  }
}
```

Now you will be able to get the value of text2 in PHP as its hidden and not disabled.Disabled element's value does not get POSTED.

Hope it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Please approve this answer if it helped. Thanks @sreekanth